# UIView in cell show wrong color after fetching from CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiview

I have a simple Todo app. in main screen I show the list of available tasks, every cell show a small UIView for category color, category name, title and date. in first launch all data shows correnct, but when I choose one of them for update and change the category with another category's color and save changes in CoreData, modal view(where I update data) disappear and NSFetchedResultController fetch new data to populate tableView, all data changes, but only color stay as before the update. NOTE: When window disappear, cell first show correct color as I updated, after second it changes to old one. I debugged the app, debugger show, that correct and new data fetched from CoreData and everything must render right, but UIView's background color is wrong.

this is my cell's code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progress: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryColorView: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

var viewModel: TaskCellViewModel! {
    didSet {

        title.text = viewModel.title
        category.text = viewModel.categoryName
        date.text = convert()
        progress.text = viewModel.isDone ? "Done" : "In Progress"
        progress.textColor = viewModel.isDone ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red
        categoryColorView.backgroundColor = Constants.colors[viewModel.categoryColor]!.color
    }
}
```

and this is a cell:

[image]

**EDIT:**
**this is save/update method, called from NewTaskViewModel:**

```
func save(completion: @escaping (AppResult<Task>) -> Void) {
    let context = CustomContext.shared.getContext

    do {
        if _task.id != "" {
            let taskFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TaskEntity> = TaskEntity.fetchRequest()
            taskFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", _task.id)
            let taskEntity = try context.fetch(taskFetchRequest).first!
            taskEntity.title = task.title
            taskEntity.date = task.date as NSDate?
            taskEntity.content = task.content
            taskEntity.isDone = task.isDone
            let categoryFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CategoryEntity> = CategoryEntity.fetchRequest()
            categoryFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", _task.category.name)
            taskEntity.category = try context.fetch(categoryFetchRequest).first!
        } else {
            let taskEntity = TaskEntity(context: context)
            taskEntity.id = UUID().uuidString
            taskEntity.title = task.title
            taskEntity.date = task.date as NSDate?
            taskEntity.content = task.content
            taskEntity.isDone = task.isDone

            let categoryFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CategoryEntity> = CategoryEntity.fetchRequest()
            categoryFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", _task.category.name)
            taskEntity.category = try context.fetch(categoryFetchRequest).first!
        }


        try context.save()

        completion(.success(task))
    } catch {
        completion(.error(error.localizedDescription))
    }

}
```

**this is the call of save/update from NewTaskViewController(modal view):**

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    switch viewModel.validation() {
    case .success(_):
        viewModel.save { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                    self.errorAlert(withMessage: error)
                }
            }
        }
    case .error(let errorMsg):
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.errorAlert(withMessage: errorMsg)
        }
    }
}
```

**tableView's cellForRowAt:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.taskCell, for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
    cell.viewModel = viewModel.getTaskCell(indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

**getTaskCell:**

```
func getTaskCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> TaskCellViewModel {
    let taskEntity = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    return TaskCellViewModel(withTask: taskEntity.convertToModel())
}
```

**taskEntity.convertToModel()**

```
@NSManaged public var id: String?
@NSManaged public var content: String?
@NSManaged public var date: NSDate?
@NSManaged public var isDone: Bool
@NSManaged public var title: String?
@NSManaged public var category: CategoryEntity?

func convertToModel() -> Task {
    var task = Task()
    task.id = self.id!
    task.title = self.title!
    task.content = self.content!
    task.isDone = self.isDone
    task.date = self.date! as Date
    task.category.name = self.category!.name!
    task.category.color = Constants.colors[self.category!.color!]!
    return task
}
```

**and NSFetchedResultControllerDelegates's:**

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TaskCell
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.getTaskCell(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
        break
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update more code for these lines you have written "but when I choose one of them for update and change the category with another category's color and save changes in CoreData, modal view(where I update data) disappear and NSFetchedResultController fetch new data to populate tableView, all data changes, but only color stay as before the update."

Comment: @ArunKumar I edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while updating try

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

instead of

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TaskCell
            cell.viewModel = viewModel.getTaskCell(indexPath: indexPath)
```

I Hope this will work.

Comment: I spent 6 hours to find this issue, you my saver. Thank you, Arun! Works as expected!

Comment: Happy to help. :)